# Is Super User connected to askquestions.in?

Tags: support, stackexchange

I posted a [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/667424/program-cant-start-because-gx6050r-dll-is-missing) yesterday. Today, when I google the problem I had, I find [my question](http://askquestions.in/program-cant-start-because-gx6050r-dll-is-missing) on askquestions.in.

I have never created a user at askquestions. Is there an official connection, or is [askquestions.in](http://askquestions.in/) "stealing" questions from superuser in order to get more hits?

This is the case for other questions as well.

Question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/667628/windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-in-custom-contex) and again at [Askquestions.in](http://askquestions.in/windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-in-custom-context-menu-command).

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: @Psycogeek: I remember I read that once. It doesn't look like Askquestions.in is complying to those rules..? There is no link to superuser, as far as i can see.

Comment: I do not know any facts. as far as I can tell it runs from a server in LA california and is owned by Sona of a country IN. http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=askquestions.in , same results from 2 locations. site was established 2 months ago. i do not observe any affiliations with SE, and I would not place my user login info on such site until I knew facts (not that you would do that)

Comment: FTR: On the Users page, the 'User's Website' is actually a link back to SuperUser. Other then that, I see no attribution

Comment: Also: It doesn't show my username, my old or my new! I'm a sad panda now :o(

Comment: Here's another one: http://www.nerdanswer.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User Contributions to Stack Exchange are licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) so there's nothing wrong in copying, assuming the attribution is given

To be clear, attribution required means:

> - Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t
>     have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> - Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> - Show the author names for every question and answer
> - Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g.,
>     https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

In this case, the site fails to do any of the above & is running violation of the licensing.

In this case, [this meta question mentions how to report such scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/133693):

> Send all reports of SCRAPERs to `team@stackexchange.com`. Please
>   include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome

Comment: Case reported. Thanks!